# Getting started with Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm going to sound like a complete newbie here but here goes...

I've just signed up for a Windows Azure account and was hoping to get a simple hello world aspx page up and running in a browser to see how it all works but I can't seem to find a simple guide to getting a very simple web application running.

I've got as far as setting up a "service" and going onto the "deploy" page but it's asking me upload an "application package".

I've looked on MSDN but there aren't any simple guides, just reams of documentation talking about "roles" and "development fabric". For somebody that is proficient in HTML/CSS and knows a little abit about asp.net it may just as well be in another language.

So, does anybody know how to upload a simple aspx page and then access it in a browser?

Jon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does [this guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/03/02/getting-started-with-windows-azure-part-2-creating-a-windows-azure-hello-world-application.aspx) help you? It seems pretty detailed for what you're looking for.

Note: When you're looking at helping documentation, I strongly urge you to focus mostly on documentation/posts dated AFTER November, 2009. It was about then that Microsoft made and released some major changes to Azure. Anything older than that might be outdated and unhelpful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Azure hosting requires credit card info :(. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're careful with your app as well. Leaving a simple HelloWorld app running 24/7 for 1 month could cost you approx $85 in fees.

($0.12/hr x 24hr x 30days = $86.40)

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/pricing/

Comment: +1 Too true! And it gets worse - I posted a link to the details in my answer below. I already had to console a coworker who ran up over $100 due to this.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download and install
        1. Windows Azure SDK: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=130232
        2. Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=128752
2. Request a Token: http://www.microsoft.com/azure
3. After getting the token create an application: https://lx.azure.microsoft.com
4. Open visual studio: new –> project –> Cloud Services –> Web Cloud Service
5. Write hello world code in the Default.aspx page (be creative)
6. Right click on your Service project (Not the _WebRole) and select publish.
7. Select Deploy and Upload you package and configurations
8. Select Run.

This from Rimon
http://blogs.msdn.com/rimontadros/archive/2009/04/17/windows-azure-hello-world-application-in-8-steps.aspx

Answer (score 2):

An application package is simply an encrypted zip of your project [here](http://www.robbagby.com/azure/azure-application-part-1-setup-and-running-hello-world/) is a good guide to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like others have covered things quite well. I just want to add two blog posts that I put up recently, specifically related to managing your account and understanding the true cost of web roles and worker roles:

First: [How to correctly set up your account to use the MSDN Premium offering](http://rdaarchitecture.blogspot.com/2010/03/azure-how-to-activate-msdn-premium.html) (assuming you have an MSDN Premium account.

Next: [The true cost of web and worker roles](http://www.davidmakogon.com/2010/03/azure-true-cost-of-web-and-worker-roles.html). This one post could save you a LOT of money. Andrew Lewis already pointed you to the pricing, but this post will illustrate how costs accrue even when your app is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the [Windows Azure Platform Training Kit](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Azure/) was pretty helpful when I was getting started.  It is simple step by step hands on stuff.