# Confused about Azure hosting and billing?

Tags: azure

I've developed a simple system using ASP.NET MVC and WCF for customers to register software and get a license key. I was thinking about using Windows Azure instead of a traditional web hosting because it seems easy to use. I'd only need one SQL database and one small VM, but I'm confused about the billing.

Does the billing only charge as people actually use it, or would I pay the fee for each CPU every hour of everyday for the whole month because that was what was available to users? So for one single cpu VM at $0.12 an hour in a 30 day month I'd pay $86.4? Or would I pay less if no one used it? Then another $9.99 for an up to 1GB database, so for my needs I'd basically pay $96.39 a month?

That seems expensive for basic web hosting, but if it's easier for someone with little hosting experience to set up and maintain as well as making it easy to expand if I suddenly got a lot of traffic then it would certainly be worth it to me.

EDIT: I think I found the answer here: [Getting started with Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524096/getting-started-with-windows-azure)

Comment: Oops - didn't see your edit - looks like you found some info already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct regarding the $0.12 / hour: you're billed based on resources consumed (meaning virtual machine instances), whether you're running at 0% cpu or 100% cpu.

While it might seem expensive compared to your average shared-hosting provider, consider that you're getting health monitoring, failover, SLA (if you have 2 or more instances) upgrade domains, etc.

I have two blog posts that go deeper into Compute Instance billing that you might find beneficial:

- [Part 1](http://architecture-blog.rdacorp.com/2010/03/azure-true-cost-of-web-and-worker-roles.html): The True Cost of Web and Worker Roles
- [Part 2](http://architecture-blog.rdacorp.com/2010/04/azure-staging-and-compute-hour-metering.html): Staging and Compute-Hour Metering

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 4):

The rule for billing is quite simple: if you look at the protal, there are the "gray" or "blue" boxes showing for a deployment.

> If the box is gray, you are OK. If the box is blue, a bill is due.

This means that charges for every hour will be made whenever the box is blue, that is: once a deployment has been done, whether it's stopped or running.

Comment: So you only pay when your app is 'live' - not while you're testing it etc?

Comment: 'live' is equivalent to 'uploaded into your service', whether it's suspended or running. So if you pause/suspend your service, you're still billed because you're consuming the physical resources.

As Maarten said, if it's blue, a bill is due. Meaning... once you upload a deployment to your service, the box is blue, letting you know there's something in it and you're being billed for it. If you suspend, you're still blue. If you delete the deployment from the service, you'll go gray, and you're... ok.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have a new feature in windows azure called WebSites. Deploying a website which have only a small amount of visits. It is simply 'free'. This is light weight website running in a shared environment.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/ -> Check for websites.